# Row wise comparisons between two Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a beginner & trying to find a solution for the below issue

I have two table with same number of column, same names and same datatype.

I'm sorting both the table by time and trying to do row wise comparison (including data in each row) using not exist operation to identify the mismatch of records. If all the rows in both table are same then I need to return True else False.

Note: No relationship between the tables to do Join.

Comment: An example of the output you want would be helpful.  It sounds like you just want to do `select * from A minus select * from B` but that's not completely clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question.

Sample tables: they have the same number of columns, with same names, same datatypes - but, you didn't say whether they contain the same number of rows. Mine don't:

```
SQL> select * from t1 order by id;

        ID NAME   COUNTRY
---------- ------ -------
         1 Little Croatia
         2 Foot   Hungary
         3 Scott  UK

SQL> select * from t2 order by id;

        ID NAME   COUNTRY
---------- ------ -------
         1 Little Croatia
         2 Michel France

SQL>
```

The idea is to compare SHA1 hash values computed on concatenated values from both tables for comparative rows (which ones? Those that share the same row number).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt_1   number;
  3    l_cnt_2   number;
  4    l_cnt     number;
  5    --
  6    cursor c1 is
  7      select id, name, country
  8        from (select id, name, country,
  9                   row_number() over (order by id) rn
 10              from t1)
 11        order by rn;
 12    cursor c2 is
 13      select id, name, country
 14        from (select id, name, country,
 15                   row_number() over (order by id) rn
 16              from t2)
 17        order by rn;
 18    c1r c1%rowtype;
 19    c2r c2%rowtype;
 20    h1  raw(20);
 21    h2  raw(20);
 22  begin
 23    -- which table is smaller (by number of rows)?
 24    select count(*) into l_cnt_1 from t1;
 25    select count(*) into l_cnt_2 from t2;
 26    l_cnt := least(l_cnt_1, l_cnt_2);
 27
 28    open c1;
 29    open c2;
 30    -- loop as many times as there are rows in a smaller table; it doesn't make
 31    -- sense comparing rows that don't have a "pair"
 32    for i in 1 .. l_cnt loop
 33      fetch c1 into c1r;
 34      fetch c2 into c2r;
 35
 36      -- SHA1 hash
 37      select sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw
 38               (c1r.id || c1r.name || c1r.country), sys.dbms_crypto.hash_sh1),
 39             sys.dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw
 40               (c2r.id || c2r.name || c2r.country), sys.dbms_crypto.hash_sh1)
 41        into h1, h2
 42        from dual;
 43
 44      dbms_output.put_line('Comparing');
 45      dbms_output.put_line('- T1: ' || c1r.id ||', '|| c1r.name ||', '|| c1r.country);
 46      dbms_output.put_line('- T2: ' || c2r.id ||', '|| c2r.name ||', '|| c2r.country);
 47
 48      if h1 = h2 then
 49         dbms_output.put_line('- Result: match');
 50      else
 51         dbms_output.put_line('- Result: no match');
 52      end if;
 53    end loop;
 54
 55    close c1;
 56    close c2;
 57  end;
 58  /
```

Result is:

```
Comparing
- T1: 1, Little, Croatia
- T2: 1, Little, Croatia
- Result: match
Comparing
- T1: 2, Foot, Hungary
- T2: 2, Michel, France
- Result: no match

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```